# How to protect passwords from a spoof server

Tags: networking, cryptography, password-protection

I have a Client-Server-Application, which allows users to run any code on the server over network. I want to protect the user from connecting to some other server, that behaves like the real thing, but steals passwords, how can I do that?
Neither the Server nor the Client can be expected to have internet access, the certificate authority is out of the question. Is there any other way to verify that it's my code I'm talking to, even if someone gets the source code?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is using SSL with a self signed certificate. Then hardcode the server's certificate into client. Most SSL libraries offer some way to roll your own certificate validation logic, or change the collection of valid CAs.

This assumes you can keep the server's certificate secret.

---

In principle [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) could be an alternative. But you should not implement it yourself, since it's very easy to make subtle mistakes that appear to work, but make the system insecure. Some SSL libraries, such as GnuTLS have support SRP.

Comment: ok what would be the way to secure the server's certificate? Anybody might buy a Server and have Administrator and hardware access.

Answer (score 0):

Is your attacker likely to gain root access to your real server? If not, then you can establish a self-signed certificate (as suggested by CodesInChaos) and rely on operating system permissions to prevent unauthorised users from reading the private key file. You can then be confident that your clients are only connecting to your real server (via SSL).

If an attacker can gain root access to your real server, you have many problems to deal with. Firstly, the attacker can read process memory at will, so any sensitive materials exposed in server memory (such as the passwords you mention) will be accessible. Also, the attacker can steal your private key and establish their own server (although why would they, when they can simply snoop on your real server memory).